# Checking for duplicate email address causing Bad Request error

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a form for creating new users and I've added `clean_email` function for checking if the email address already exists like this:

```py
class NewUserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = '__all__'
    
    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')

        try:
            match = User.objects.get(email = email)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return email
        raise forms.ValidationError('User with this email address already exists.')
```

Unfortunately, after I try to test this by attempting to register a user with an email address that already exists I get the `This page isn't working` error in my browser. I'm not sure why this is happening, can anyone help?

**Edit:** I figured out what the problem was, now it sort of works. It doesn't allow me to create a user with the duplicate email address but how do I display the error message on the site?

**Edit_2:** View code

```
form = NewUserForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    data = form.cleaned_data
else:
    form = NewUserForm()
return redirect('newuserpage')
```

Comment: Did you copy/paste your code or type it by hand? `__all__` should be string.

Comment: I copy pasted it but it is a string in my code, dunno how this happend.

Comment: [Customizing error ouput](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/api/#how-errors-are-displayed) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/#rendering-form-error-messages).

Comment: I must be doing something wrong, I've looked over the documentation but I still can't display the error message.

Comment: Post your view code, you must pass the form again to the template with the errors. Meaning: don't redirect on error.

Comment: I've updated my question with my view code.

Comment: Oh I'm dumb, I figured out what you mean by "pass the form again to the template with the errors", thank you

Comment: Don't worry about it. It's just something that needs to connect in your brain. And remember, a template cannot render what it doesn't know about. There's no magical view/template connection, everything that is a variable in a template, has an source that can be located (view, generic.base.ContextMixin and context processors are the main sources).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some problems with my views. I fixed it like this:

```
form = NewUserForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    data = form.cleaned_data
else:
    return render(request, 'newuser.html',  {'form':form})
return redirect('newuserpage')
```